# C++ check if value was assigned to member of class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, operator-overloading

I have a uni assignment in which I have to create a custom template which acts as an array of doubles. It also has to implement a sorting algorithm which sorts the elements in descending order. I designed the template so it has an internal array of doubles with the length declared by the user (MyArray<10> contains a double array with a length of 10). My custom array will only be filled up with doubles in ascending order from myArr[0] and values won't be changed once assigned, but they can be any value so I can't have a magic constant to keep track of them. Instead I have to check the number of assignments to the array so when I call the sort() method, it knows which is the last changed element.

My subscript operator:

```
Proxy &operator[](int elem) {
    if(elem > arr_size - 1) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");
    }
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    return Proxy(*this, elem);
}
```

And the proxy class which is inside the F8 class:

```
class Proxy {
    private:
        F8 &a;
        int id;
    public:
        Proxy(F8 &a, int id) { this.a = a; this.id = id; };
        int& operator=(int x) { curr_num++; return a.arr[id]; }
};
```

**Is there a way to check if operator[] is in an assignment (or if it is an lvalue)?** I have tried it with a proxy class but it just seems too complicated for a beginner C++ class and that way I have to implement all of the operators (the values get compared etc, so when with operator[] I return a double it can be compared directly, but when I return the Proxy class, the compiler gives an error for every operator because they don't exist, and the task doesn't ask me to implement all the operators needed for comparison).

Thank you for your time!

**Edit:** I get the following error when I try to return a proxy class in which I can keep track of the assignment operator:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'F8<433>::Proxy')
```

Also to make things clear: the array will be filled in the ascending order of indexes, so after I assign a value to myArr[0] comes myArr[1].

Comment: do you have to use `operator[]` ? You wont have the problem when you use two distinct methods for assignment and for retrieving the value

Comment: btw, where is your code? "..the compiler gives an error for every operator.." what are the errors?

Comment: code and errors should be included in the question. See also [mcve]

Comment: your problem description isnt clear. You say " My custom array will only be filled up with doubles in ascending order" but then whats the point of sorting it ?

Comment: You must initialise reference members in the constructor's initialiser list. (And you should do it with other members as well instead of assigning to them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems to me like you are looking for a user defined conversion.

```
class Proxy {
    private:
        F8 &a;
        int id;
    public:
        Proxy(F8 &a, int id) { this.a = a; this.id = id; };
        int& operator=(int x) { curr_num++; return a.arr[id]; }

        operator int() const { return a.arr[id]; }
        //       ^ int or double? You say double but your example code seems to be using int.
};
```

Not sure how/what your assignment operator is supposed to do. Right now it's only returning a value from your array but not actually assigning anything.

What about something like

```
int& operator=(int x) { curr_num++; a.arr[id]=x; return a.arr[id]; }
```